# Append each element to closest anchor

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="prevnextbg">prevnextbg</div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <div class="prevnextbg">prevnextbg</div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

I want to take each `.prevnextbg` and add it inside the `<a>` inside it's `.col` div.

I tried like so but that just adds all the `.prevnextbg` divs to the first `<a>`:

```
$('div.prevnextbg').appendTo('.col a');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in one call, you need a loop:

```
$(".prevnextbg").each(function() {
    $(this).siblings("a").append(this);
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$(".prevnextbg").each(function() {
  $(this).siblings("a").append(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
    <div class="prevnextbg">prevnextbg</div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <div class="prevnextbg">prevnextbg</div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

If the `a` elements may not be *siblings*, you might do

```
$(".prevnextbg").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("a").append(this);
});
```

instead.

---

That said, it would be much better to modify the markup to start with, rather than rearranging it after the fact.